# Performance in SQL proc, convert ssrs mutli-value parameter to table for join; use 'where like' clause; or other?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

SQL table with ID field and "checkbox" field.

SSRS report allows to select multiple values for "checkbox".
I use SSRS join to pass the multi-value parameter SQL proc as a comma delimited list.

I could convert the comma delimited list into a temp table/table variable and then do an inner join with my table.

I could add a leading and trailing comma to the comma delimited list and then select from my table using "where @ssrsparameter like '%,' + checkbox + ',%'
Any opinions on performace, design philosophy?  Or any other better ideas?

Comment: If your table has an index on The Column then it will always be faster to split and join, performance wise. With no indexes it will likely be faster. As mentioned by @David Browne SQL injection is another issue to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could add a leading and trailing comma to the comma delimited list and then select from my table using "where @ssrsparameter like '%,' + checkbox + ',%'

That would be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  So parse the list.  There's even a built-in function to do it now: [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: SQL 2012 here (so no string_split function), but valid point nonetheless.